# Convert list of list to list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've a list like this:

```
a=['b',['c']]
```

I wish to convert it to:

```
a=['b','c']
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What if input is `['ab',['c']]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* (which is pretty fast in this case):

```
print [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> l = ['b', ['c']]
>>> [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
['b', 'c']
```

**Note:**

This will only work if the list has strings of length 1, as @RemcoGerlich commented.

**Edit:**

If the string has more than 1 character, you can use the following approach (note that `compiler` was deprecated in Python 3):

```
from compiler.ast import flatten    
print flatten(a)
```

Comment: That will treat longer strings as sequences of characters, or bytes in Python 3.

Comment: Okay, so what if it's more than 1? Then how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using map:

```
reduce((lambda arr,x: arr + list(x)),a,[])
```

Example:

```
>>> a=['b',['c']]
>>> a = reduce((lambda arr,x: arr + list(x)),a,[])
>>> a
['b', 'c']
```